# How to connect a Xamarin Client to Akka.net

Tags: c#, xamarin, akka.net

I've being trying to find how to connect a Xamarin or Universal app to Akka.net. I'd like to receive notifications from actors directly to the client like Orleans [does](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Getting-Started-With-Orleans/Developing-a-Client.html). I did not find anything like this in the getakka web page. Is something that is not covered by the framework or it's because there are no .net Core libraries for Xamarin and Universal apps?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no .Net Core support as yet.

Referring to [this post](http://www.aaronstannard.com/dotnetcore-boil-ocean/) by one of the primary owners of Akka.net, specifically half way down

> after yesterday’s announcements I’m wondering if the .NET Core roadmap is even valid anymore. We had talked about starting work on Akka.NET for .NET Core in 2016. As of today, I’m thinking that .NET Core probably won’t be ready until much later than that.
>
> ... I can’t have that, and I’m fortunate enough to be in a position where I can and am choosing not to. I’m sticking with .NET 4.5.2 until .NET Core is solid.

Although this was dated May last year, I'm not aware of any changes on this front.  I may be wrong, however.

Comment: So in order to provide a pub/sub communication between the actor and the client I have to implement it by myself basically, using XMPP  or MQTT?

Comment: Yes, if you need to connect something built with Xamarin to an Akka.Net system, you won't be able to use Akka.remote.  How you want to approach that communication is up to you.